# Android Selecting a drawable from level-list in XML

Tags: android, xml, android-drawable, xml-drawable

How can I select **in XML**, for an `android:drawable` property, one of the drawables defined in the level-list XML?
I am defining the drawables in the level-list XML itself, to avoid defining many small XML files.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<level-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:maxLevel="0">
        <shape 
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient 
                android:startColor="@color/empty" 
                android:endColor="@android:color/white"
                android:angle="90" />

        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:maxLevel="1">
        <shape
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="rectangle" >
            <gradient 
                android:startColor="@color/low"
                android:endColor="@android:color/white"
                android:angle="90" />

        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:maxLevel="2">
        <shape 
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient 
                android:startColor="@color/middle"
                android:endColor="@android:color/white"
                android:angle="90" />

        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:maxLevel="3">
        <shape 
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient 
                android:startColor="@color/high"
                android:endColor="@android:color/white"
                android:angle="90" />

        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:maxLevel="4">
        <shape 
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient 
                android:startColor="@color/full"
                android:endColor="@android:color/white"
                android:angle="90" />

        </shape>
    </item>

</level-list>
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible. I was just searching with the same idea in mind, expecting something like an attribute for the `ImageView`. Something like `Android:level`.

But no, the `setLevel` method has no equivalent in XML attributes. You (and I) must call `setLevel` programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

In API 24 (and above) this feature is now supported; `android:level` found in the `<scale>` element which Specifies the initial drawable level in the range 0 to 10000 and can be used in `<layer-list>` as thus;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background"
          android:gravity="center_vertical|fill_horizontal">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"
            android:tint="?attr/colorControlNormal">
            <size android:height="4dp" />
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white_disabled_material" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress"
          android:gravity="center_vertical|fill_horizontal">
        <scale android:scaleWidth="100%"
            android:level="2000">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle"
                android:tint="?attr/colorControlActivated" >
                <size android:height="4dp" />
                <solid android:color="@android:color/black" />
            </shape>
        </scale>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress"
          android:gravity="center_vertical|fill_horizontal">
        <scale android:scaleWidth="100%"
            android:level="1000">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle"
                android:tint="?attr/colorControlActivated" >
                <size android:height="4dp" />
                <solid android:color="@android:color/white_disabled_material" />
            </shape>
        </scale>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

to change the level dynamically you then call `setLevel` programatically